# Yii error message language vs content language

Tags: yii

We are developing a multi-lingual application with Yii and are setting the language of the website with the Yii::app()->language setting.  The problem is that when we switch the language in this way, all of Yii's built-in error messages also change to display in that language.  This makes debugging a bit irritating as I have to set the language to English and then reload the page to read the error.

I've tried using Yii::app()->souceLanguage = 'en_US', but this doesn't seem to make any difference to the error messages.  Any idea how to set up Yii to display the site's content in one language (using Yii::t()) and the error messages in another?

Comment: An example of a built-in error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override CPhpMessageSource::loadMessages() with something like following:

```
protected function loadMessages($category, $language)
{
    if ($category === 'yii') {
        return array();
    } else {
        return parent::loadMessages($category, $language);
    }
}
```